# Woocommerce Accomodation booked dates show fully booked

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I am not sure if I do it all well but after one booking, the range displays fully booked.

[image]

In my availability configurations here are what I put.
[image]

Can someone guide in this ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pass it. The issue was handled with a new commit [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-accommodation-bookings/pull/122/commits/a981a43bbcc1e9837be82737792b9015ca9751d9)